# Update database entry using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello i am using mongoose.

I have built this query that finds my desired project :

```
const projects = await ClientManagers.findOne({'project.contactPerson.work_email' : 'testing@email.com'} , { 'project.$.companyName': 1 });
```

this returns an object from my database like this  :

```
{
 'projectName' : 'x',
  'companyName' : 'x bv'
}
```

How can i update the company name to be 'Y bv' instead of 'x bv'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your document structure,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f2ae5a4b1549ac0460920dd"),
    "projectName" : "A",
    "project" : [ 
        {
            "companyName" : "T1",
            "contactPerson" : {
                "work_email" : "t1@gmail.com"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "companyName" : "T2",
            "contactPerson" : {
                "work_email" : "t2@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Single Update [updateOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html)

If you know `email` will be unique and want to update single document then use `updateOne()`.

- first is query part to find condition, email `t1@gmail.com`
- second is set/update part, here `$` is for array because `project` is an array, update `companyName` to `T1 Company`

```
await ClientManagers.updateOne(
    { 'project.contactPerson.work_email': 't1@gmail.com' },
    {
        $set: { "project.$.companyName": "T1 Companmy" }
    }
)
```

#### Multiple Update [updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html)

If `email` is not unique and want to update everywhere then use `updateMany()`, it will update every matching documents.

```
await ClientManagers.updateMany(
    { 'project.contactPerson.work_email': 't1@gmail.com' },
    {
        $set: { "project.$.companyName": "T1 Company" }
    }
)
```

> Not suggesting [update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html) method to use, because its deprecated in mongoose and will give [Deprecation Warnings](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html)
> , this function is replaced with `updateOne()`, `updateMany()` and `replaceOne()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Good start. Mongo has better documentation with examples. I suggest you to refer that also.

use `update`

```
db.collection.update({companyName:'x bv'}, {"$set":{"companyName":y}})
```

Mongo is case sensitive. So name should match exactly.

`update` updates one document. To update multiple, use `updateMany` or `multi:true` option with `update` or `findOneAndMondify` for one update for `find and update` case.