# Mongodb update string in nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pymongo

I have this collection :

```
[
  {
    title: 'space1',
    directories: [
                  { 
                   path: 'dir1/',
                   id: 1
                  },
                  {
                   path: 'dir1/dir2/',
                   id: 
                  }
                 ]
  }

]
```

I want to rename `directories.path` start with `dir1/` and replace this part with `dir3/`, result:

```
[
  {
    title: 'space1',
    directories: [
                  { 
                   path: 'dir3/',
                   id: 1
                  },
                  {
                   path: 'dir3/dir2/',
                   id: 
                  }
                 ]
  }

]
```

i know must use $regex and [$replaceOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceOne/) but I don't know how

Comment: are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63270715/8987128

Comment: @turivishal hi, no .... i want to check in one document, for each `directories.path` is `dir1/` then replace this part of string with `dir3/ ` ..imo is dynamic input

Comment: You need to use the [filtered positional array operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html#update-all-documents-that-match-arrayfilters-in-an-array) `$[id]` for that with an update operation.

Comment: @prasad_ hi, please can you show me how use `$[]` array filter operation with `$replaceOne` pipeline operation?

Comment: You cannot use that operator with `replaceOne`. `replaceOne` may not be the correct update method in such case (since you want to update specific elements in an array).

Comment: @prasad_ what is your solution?

Comment: _Correction from my previous comments_. This is the one you can use: [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html#example-5).